# How to make links selected when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a trouble on adding a jquery code to a landing page so that when I scroll down among the sections the relevant sections should be shown in the navbar links by adding a class named clicked. I have added the code snippet that I am currently working on for your reference.. :-) 
Any help would be gladly appreciated. :-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link").click(function(event){
        ------ Scroll code ------------
        $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        $(event.target).addClass("clicked"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You're question is unclear, you ask something about scrolling but you're also talking about clicking on a link. Are you looking for something like Twitter Bootstrap's scrollspy? (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Comment: Yeah that's the one I was looking for. Sorry for the unclear question :( Do you know how to achieve the same effect as in scrollspy to the code snippet above with some jquesry codes. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add an `onClick` event handler for that. The approach you should be using is not that difficult.

First you need to know your current scrolling position, which you can retrieve using:

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

Then you need to know the position of bottom of the visible portion, which is actually the scrolling position + the height of the window:

```
var btm = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
```

Now we need to check if the section is above the bottom portion (that means it's visible), so in order to do that we need to get the position of the section. You can do that by using:

```
var titlePos = $($(myLink).attr("href")).offset().top;
```

What happens here is that we're going to look for the section that is referred to by the navbar link and then get it's offset (that's the position of where it's located on the document). You get both the `left` and `top` offset, but in this case we only need to get the `top` offset.

The only thing you need to do know is automate this for all links in your navigation, you can do that for example by doing:

```
$(".nav li a").each(function() {
    var titlePos = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
});
```

The next step is that we're going to look if the position of the title is above the bottom of the screen, that means that that section is/was visible. You can do that by using:

```
var btm = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
$(".nav li a").each(function() {
    var titlePos = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
    if (titlePos < btm) {
         $(this).addClass("visited");
    }
});
```

Now there is only one problem. Sections that are above the screen (= sections you already passed/read) are also above the bottom of the screen, which means that with this code they will be active as well.

To fix that, we need to remove the `.visited` class from the previous link the moment we know that the next section is visible. You can do that by using:

```
$(this).parents("li").prev().children("a").removeClass("visited");
```

This goes to the link just before the link that's active and remove the `.visited` class from it, so actually only the last visible section is marked as visible.

Now you just add all of this to a `scroll` event handler and trigger it once to initialize the navigation. The code would become something like:

```
$(this).scroll(function() {
    var btm = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    $(".nav li a").removeClass("visited").each(function() {
        var titlePos = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
        if (titlePos < btm) {
             $(this).addClass("visited");
             $(this).parents("li").prev().children("a")
                 .removeClass("visited");
        }
    });
}).trigger("scroll");
```

Also notice the small change, when I scroll, I first remove the `.visited` class from all navigation links. I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52mPf/1/) demonstrating this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this codes. I will try to implement it and tell you what happened. :-)

Comment: If you're not happy about it you can always google `jQuery scrollspy`, I'm pretty sure you will find a suitable implementation without the need of an entire UI toolkit like Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: I am really happy about this. Thanks again for providing me a step by step guidance on how to do this with relevant example codes. I am still reading the tut you sent me carefully to implement it successfully. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: It didn't work since I think I haven't changed the code correctly. I also need it to change the class when the required title reaches the top not when it is at the bottom.

Comment: Normally you should be able to do that with my explanation. I told you how to get the current scrolling position and how to get the position of the title, now you should be able to replace the `if(titlePos < btm)` with what you need.